# Simple HTML DOM php file_get_html не загружает html польность

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Пытаюсь получить html страницы посредством file_get_html, но получаю код страницы не полностью (хочу достать head, но получаю только часть скелета HTML)

```
$ret = file_get_html('http://hbox.by/');
echo($ret);
```

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Можно просто сделать GET-запрос curl'ом, чтобы точно получить весь документ

Comment: @lezhni ничем ему курл не поможет. file_get_contents вполне себе рабочий инструмент. а у топикстартера сто пудово просто контент страницы грузится аяксом. готов спорить, что получаемое тело страницы как и положено заканчивается на `</html>` либо сервер какими то фильтрами отсекает попытки парсеров и ботов и отдает что-то обрезанное. Но это вопрос к прописке различных заголовков и прочей эмуляции работы обычного юзера,а никак не использования курла

Comment: Понял. Я предположил, что file_get_html получает только body